# Не видит textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea

Доброе утро.
Суть проблемы: есть `Javascript` + `HTML` форма для отправки ошибок найденных на сайте. Нужно ее сделать через `AJAX` (без перезагрузки страницы). Проблема в том что `jQuery` и AJAX не видят сам тексты ошибки в элементе `textarea`. То есть все данные из инпутов ajax-ом отправляются в файл обработчик, а вот текстареа не хочет + пробовал вывести ее содержимое через `alert ()` - нечего не выводится. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

```
    <textarea id="say_error" class="error" name="say_error" rows="10"   cols="45"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="urlsw" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"/>
    <div id="center"><input  type="button" name="send_text_error" id="send_text_error" value="Отправить"/></div> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = $("input[name=urlsw]").val();
        var user = <?php echo $_SESSION['id_user'] ?>;
        var text = $(".error").val();
        $("#send_text_error").click(function(){ 
                alert(text);
                $.post("http://zoobonus.com/error_ajax.php", {user: user,  link: url, text: text}, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });

            });
    });
```

Переменные url и user оно видит и передает а переменную text - нет. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная `text` создается сразу после загрузки страницы, перенесите эту строку в обработчик события `click`.

Comment: А, тоесть она изначально создается пустой! Точно, заработало, спасибо!